# Get Name from one model to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two models:

One is for Brands

```
public class BrandVM
    {
        public BrandVM() { }

        public BrandVM(BrandDTO row)
        {
            Id = row.Id;
            Name = row.Name;
            Description = row.Description;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual BicycleVM BicycleVM { get; set; }
    }
```

and second for Products

```
public class BicycleVM
    {
        public BicycleVM() { }

        public BicycleVM(BicycleDTO row)
        {
            Id = row.Id;
            CategoryId = row.CategoryId;
            BrandId = row.BrandId;
            Mark = row.Mark;
            Year = row.Year;
            Color = row.Color;
            ImageName = row.ImageName;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Brand")]
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        DisplayName("Image")]
        public string ImageName { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Brands { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> GalleryImages { get; set; }
    }
```

public string Brand { get; set; } doesnt exist in the table, it only uses for view.

I need somehow get all Brands from one table and insert them in property Brand. Id from Bramds must match with BrandId.

How it looks like for me: I'm getting all the brand's names and id's from the first table. Compare BrandId from products with Id in Brands. If they match, than product.Brand = brand.Name.

Tried this:

```
List<BicycleVM> listOfBicycleVM;
using (Db db = new Db())
{
  var init = db.Bicycles.ToArray()
      .Where(x => catId == null || catId == 0 || x.CategoryId == catId)
      .Select(x => new BicycleVM(x));


  listOfBicycleVM = init.ToList();

  var brand = db.Brands.ToList();

  listOfBicycleVM.ForEach(bicycle => bicycle.Brand = brand
          .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == bicycle.BrandId).ToString());
```

No luck :(

Comment: dont .ToArray() on Bicycles

Comment: this is a design issue, so you have two VM you want to combine into One?I think without properly thinking about it you are likely to break the code. db.Bicycles returns bicycles only and db.brands returns brands. You need a class that will accept brand and bicycle in the constructor if you want to populate those two.

Comment: without ToArray() it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to combine two `ViewModels` together for a single view, that defeats the purpose of them. You can however combine two models into a single `ViewModel`.

Create a single `ViewModel` which contains all of the data needed and call it something like "BicycleBrandVM". Populate this either in the controller or where ever you are populating the `ViewModels` just now then pass it through to your `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this workaround

```
var brand = db.Brands.ToArray().Select(x => new BrandVM(x));
                foreach (var item in listOfBicycleVM)
                {
                    if( brand.Any(x => x.Id == item.BrandId))
                    {
                        item.Brand = brand.First(c => c.Id == item.BrandId).Name;
                    }
                }
```

seems like this it can work without this part

```
if( brand.Any(x => x.Id == item.BrandId))
```

Will try later